# Player:GetAccountId() is passed a table argument

Tags: azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I've been trying to use

```
local function TestFunction(event, player, command)
    local accountId = Player:GetAccountId()
end
```

whichs 2nd line was copied straight from the [ElunaLua wiki](https://elunaluaengine.github.io/Player/GetAccountId.html).
On execcution I received the error

```
calling 'GetAccountName' on bad self (bad argument : Player expected, got table)
```

I suspected the "Player" to be a global argument, wondering how it can be a table and how to use said table?

Answer (score 1):

"Player" is actually a global table that holds the functions you can use on a Player type variable.
So that player has all functions in "Player" table.
This is why doing Player:GetAccountId() caused a bit of a different error than something like Player variable not existing.

To make it work, i used "player:GetAccountId()" instead of a capital P. This passes the method the variable named "player".